# Changing font color using TColorBox

Tags: delphi

Delphi v7

I have yet another remedial question.

Using a `TColorBox` I would like to change the font color in each of 4 RichEdit controls. I am using an `OnClick` event of the color box.

**This procedure works fine for one rich edit control.**

```
    procedure TForm1.cmbFColorClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin

     reProc.SelAttributes.Color := cmbFColor.Selected;

    end;
```

If I try to write the same code for each of the richedit controls it will change the font color in all of the richedit control at the same time.

**Example:** I select and change the text color on one richedit control, then I change the text color on a different control the text color on both richedit controls is changed at the same time.

**Example**

```
 procedure TForm1.cmbFColorClick(Sender: TObject);
     begin

      reProc.SelAttributes.Color := cmbFColor.Selected;
      reApp.SelAttributes.Color := cmbFColor.Selected;
      reServ.SelAttributes.Color := cmbFColor.Selected;

     end;
```

**This procedure does not work at all**

```
procedure TForm1.cmbFColorClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if ActiveControl is TDBRichEdit then
   with ActiveControl as TDBRichEdit do
    SelAttributes.Color := cmbFColor.Selected;

  end;
```

Is there a way I can change the text color on all of the richedit controls without affecting any of the other controls?

Comment: I've no idea what you want. Which rich edit control(s) do you want to be modified?

Comment: Why would other controls be affected from the text color change of richedit controls?

Comment: You want to change the color only of the last active `TDBRichEdit` control?

Comment: 1. I want to change the font color in the richedit control on the page in which I am working.

Comment: 2. I don't know why the other richedit is affected, unless I have to unselect the prev one programatically.

Comment: Changing the color of the last active sounds promising. I need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the active control is your TColorBox not the richeditboxes, because only one control can be the active control. If i remember right, this control which have the focus.

So you have to implement a procedure like this. 
and you have remember by code, which was the last, active richedit.

procedure changeColor(edit : Trichedit) ; 
begin

```
procedure changeColor(edit:Trichedit); 
begin
     edit.SelAttributes.Color := cmbFColor.Selected;
end;
```

Kind Regards

Comment: I understand what you said. I don't know how to code anything of the last active. I will work on that.

Comment: The problem is that when I select text  on one REcomtrol, then move to another REcontrol the text is still selected in the first one, so the selected text in both is changed. How to unselect by code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. In a PageControl OnChange event I set the RichEdit SelLength to "0" for each rich edit control.

Thank you for your help. It gave me the idea.

Comment: That sounds like a remedy rather then a cure to the problem.

Comment: It's easy to solve the problem, but this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm piecing things together from this question, your last question, the comments to those questions, and your answers to those questions.

What you are trying to do is modify `SelAttributes.Color` for a single rich edit control. The problem is working out which rich edit control to operate on.

Let us suppose you had the following function available:

```
function ActiveRichEdit: TRichEdit;
```

Then you could simply write:

```
ActiveRichEdit.SelAttributes.Color := NewColor;
```

Or, if there was a possibility that there was no rich edit control active:

```
if ActiveRichEdit<>nil then
  ActiveRichEdit.SelAttributes.Color := NewColor;
```

So, how do we implement `ActiveRichEdit`? Well, it seems that you have a control with multiple pages, each containing a distinct rich edit. That sounds very much like a page control to me.

I'm going to assume that your page control is called `PageControl`, and the tab sheets called `TabSheet1`, `TabSheet2` etc., and rich edit controls are named `RichEdit1`, `RichEdit2` etc. But if your names are different then you'll need to adapt this code.

```
function TForm1.ActiveRichEdit: TRichEdit;
begin
  if PageControl.ActivePage=TabSheet1 then
    Result := RichEdit1
  else if PageControl.ActivePage=TabSheet2 then
    Result := RichEdit2
  else if PageControl.ActivePage=TabSheet3 then
    Result := RichEdit3
  // etc. etc.
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Now, there are other ways to do this. You could make an array of rich edit references that could be indexed by `PageControl.ActivePageIndex`. And there are indeed yet more possible solutions.

But the key is to use the `ActivePage` or `ActivePageIndex` properties of the page control to work out which rich edit control to operate on.